# Getting 403 Forbidden error in django applicaion if user is logged-in in my website. I am not getting this error for anonymous user

Tags: django, ajax, django-rest-framework

I am new to django and ajax both.
I am getting 403 error only if I am logged-in user. If am logged out same is working fine.
Here is my ajax call:

```
$("div#mainCont").on("click","#detail_icon", function(){
   var _tickName = $(this).parent().attr('id');
   var csrf = $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val();
   
   $.ajax({
       method: "POST",
       url: 'performance',
       data:JSON.stringify({
           csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrf,
           ticker: _tickName
  
       }),
       success: function (data) {
        console.log(data)
       }
});
```

This is my view:

```py
class PerformanceView(APIView):
    def get(self,request, format=None):
        queryset = Advice.objects.all()
        serializer = AdviceSerializers(queryset,many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)   

    def post(self, request):
        data=json.loads(request.body)
        print(data)
        queryset = Stocks.objects.filter(ticker=data["ticker"])
        serializer = PerformanceSerializers(queryset,many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you get an error message in the 403 page?

Comment: I am getting this error on my server side

Forbidden: /performance
[04/Jan/2022 13:06:00] "POST /performance HTTP/1.1" 403 45

Comment: @NickODell any help?

Comment: You should post the detailed error message from the 403 page. If you don't post it, there's no way anyone can help you. Beyond that I have no further advice.